# drawRect UIView resizable height inside UITableViewCell

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, uiview

I started playing around with drawRect method for a UIView trying to make a message bubble.  This is what I got so far (it's not pretty but it's a start; open to suggestions to make it look better):

```
- (id)initWithFrame:(CGRect)frame{
    self = [super initWithFrame:frame];
    if (self) {
        self.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
        [self setFrame:CGRectMake(60, 5, 250, 50)];
        self.contentMode = UIViewContentModeRedraw;
    }
    return self;
}

- (void)drawRect:(CGRect)rect{
    CGContextRef context = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext();
    CGContextSetLineWidth(context, 1.0);
    CGContextSetStrokeColorWithColor(context, [UIColor blueColor].CGColor);
    CGContextBeginPath(context);
    CGContextMoveToPoint(context, 0, 11);
    CGContextAddCurveToPoint(context,5,12.5,10,15,10,10);
    CGContextAddCurveToPoint(context, 10, 1, 20, 1, 20, 1);
    CGContextAddCurveToPoint(context, 20, 1, 50, 1, 240, 1);
    CGContextAddCurveToPoint(context, 240, 1, 250, 1, 249, 15);
    CGContextAddCurveToPoint(context, 249, 30, 249, 40, 249, 40);
    CGContextAddCurveToPoint(context, 249, 45, 245, 49, 240, 49);
    CGContextAddCurveToPoint(context, 240, 49, 200, 49, 20, 49);
    CGContextAddCurveToPoint(context, 15, 49, 10, 45, 10, 40);
    CGContextAddCurveToPoint(context, 10, 40, 10, 30, 10, 20);
    CGContextAddCurveToPoint(context, 10, 20, 3, 20, 0, 10);
    CGContextStrokePath(context);
}
```

In my custom cell I have a UILabel and I'm setting the custom view like this:

```
Bubble *bubble = [[Bubble alloc]init];
_bubble = bubble;
[self addSubview:_bubble];

UILabel *message = [[UILabel alloc]init];
message.backgroundColor = [UIColor yellowColor];
message.layer.borderWidth = 1;
[message setFont:[UIFont systemFontOfSize:12]];
message.numberOfLines = 0;
message.preferredMaxLayoutWidth = 200;
_message = message;
[bubble addSubview:_message];
```

I resize the UILabel using this method:

```
-(UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath{
    //...
    CGFloat height = [self heightForText:[[individualMessages 
        objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] valueForKey:@"theMessage"]];
    cell.message.frame = CGRectMake(20, 5, 220, height);
    //...
    return cell;
}

- (CGFloat)heightForText:(NSString*)text{
    ChatCell *cell = [[ChatCell alloc]init];
    cell.message.text = text;
    cell.message.font = [UIFont systemFontOfSize:12];
    [cell.message sizeToFit];
    return cell.message.frame.size.height;
}
```

My question is how can I pass the height of the "message" UILabel to the subclassed UIView and draw the bubble?  Right now I'm just including the subclass in the custom cell but of course that's not resizing.  Is there a way to pass the height to the UIView and include it later to the cell?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`self.bounds.size` should give you the size of the view in the `drawRect` method.

You should also set the `contentMode` property of the view to `UIViewContentModeRedraw` so that `drawRect` is called when the view is resized. Otherwise, your existing bubble may just get stretched when the view resizes.

Comment: Ok, questions...where should I add the view?  Inside the custom cell?  Where to set these because I'm calculating my UILabel height from the cellForRowAtIndexPath:.  Where should I add `self.bounds.size` since I don't know what the size will be?

Comment: Right, the view goes in the custom cell, presumably behind the label, so that the label appears to be inside the bubble.  Also presumably you're using auto layout to properly size the view when the cell resizes.  In the `drawRect` method, `self.bounds.size` *tells* you the current size of the view. For example, if you need to know the height of the view, you could say `CGFloat height = self.bounds.size.height;`  The system software sets the size for you when the view resizes.  All you need to do is draw the bubble the correct size based on the view's `self.bounds.size`.

Comment: I know I'm bugging you with this because I don't exactly understand how the drawRect method works and how to "reload" the view.  I updated  my question with more info of what I have...STILL, no idea how to set a different height for the "Bubble" view.  In the cellForRowAtIndexPath???

Comment: One of the methods in the `UITableViewDelegate` protocol is the `tableView:heightForRowAtIndexPath:` method. You should return the correct size for the cell from that method.

Comment: I'm using that method for resizing the cell using `boundingRectWithSize:` to get the height of the cell.  I should resize the bubble view from that method?

Comment: You can use auto-layout to automatically adjust the size of the bubble. If you don't want to use auto-layout, you can still set the `autoresizingMask` of the bubble view to `UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleHeight | UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleWidth`, and that should resize the bubble when the cell resizes. As a last resort, you can override the `layoutSubviews` method of your custom `UITableViewCell` subclass to resize the bubble yourself.

Comment: Finally figured out how it works, or at least how to get it to work.  Inside the cellForRowAtIndexPath I'm setting the frame of the bubble with appropriate height, that apparently redraws the view with, like you said, `CGFloat height = self.bounds.size.height;`.  Thanks!